# Complement of a set

Tags: calculus

Suppose I have a set defined by:
\begin{align}
A=\{(x,y): \min_z f(x,y,z) >d \}
\end{align}

what is the compliment of this set:
Is it

\begin{align}
A^c=\{(x,y): \min_z f(x,y,z) \le d \}
\end{align}

or is it

\begin{align}
A^c=\{(x,y): \max_z f(x,y,z) \le d \}
\end{align}

Thank you very much.

Comment: It would be the first one.

Consider $f(x,y,z) = \sin (x+y+z)$ and $d = \frac{1}{2}$. There are $(x,y)$ in both $A$ and the second option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each choice of $(x,y)$ and $d$, there are three possibilities:

1. $\min_z f(x,y,z) > d$
2. $\min_z f(x,y,z) \leq d$
3. $\min_z f(x,y,z)$ does not exist

Therefore, the complement of $A$ would be

$A^c = \{(x,y) : \min_z f(x,y,z) \leq d \text{ or does not exist}\}$

Comment: what if I put a an infimum instead of minimum would it change anything???

Comment: The infimum always exists (in $[-\infty,+\infty]$), @user63050, so option 3. would vanish.

Comment: Also, if condition 2 wins. Measure of A would be 0, correct?